# Pass LaTeX options with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I use the package "answers" in a `Markdown` file. After compilation with `Pandoc` the PDF I get is ok (solutions at the right place) but the option of the following LaTeX command `\Optionsolutionfile{ans}[ex1]` produces the writing of `[ex1]`. How to avoid that?

I precise that there are two series of exercises in my document and each series is followed by the solutions.

That's why I use `\Optionsolutionfile{ans}[ex1]` and then `\Optionsolutionfile{ans}[ex2]` at another place.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it works even with pandoc old version (1.12 debian jessie)

In the file default.latex I've created a newcommand

```
\newcommand{\fic}[1]{ \Optionsolutionfile{ans}[ex#1] }
```

and inside my file.md I call the command by

```
\fic {1}
```

at the right place to get the solutions of the first serie of exercises and the

```
\fic {2}
```

to get the second serie of solutions etc...

Answer (score 4):

Pandoc doesn't like the option in brackets **after** the latex command. In order to make it work you have to use a recent version of pandoc that supports generic raw attributes. Now you can create a raw latex block around the offending command:

````
```{=latex}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ex1] 
```
````

Or inline:

```
`\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]`{=latex}
```

Comment: Thanks DG but it's not good. Which version of pandoc should I use ?

Comment: It works with the [most recent](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.0.1.1): 2.0.1.1